# Making a graphics object move

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paintcomponent

In my code I override the `paintComponent` method and draw a rectangle inside JPanel.
The JPanel is then added to JFrame and I use a method that updates the position of the rectangle via a Thread.

The rectangle does actually move .. but only when I minimize the window and maximize it back again. So in other words.. it doesn't do it as I'm looking at it.. the rectangle will just sit there.. but after I minimize and bring the window back up, the rectangle will have moved.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the code, its hard to tell without seeing your current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you forgot to call the [Repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) of the JPanel whose `paintComponent` you are overriding everytime you update the object. The reason you are only seeing the change on minimize/maximize is because that is when swing calls the repaint of the component.